# Auto-complete in a Spyder IPython console

Tags: python, autocomplete, ide, ipython, spyder

**Is there a straight-forward way to get a Spyder IPython console to support autocomplete?**

I find Spyder's autocomplete functionality, provided in the standard python console, to be useful. For example:

[image]

I'd like to switch to an Ipython console (within Spyder) but it doesn't seem to provide autocomplete. Is there an easy way to enable it?

Spyder version 2.3.5.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) Sorry, but there is no support for autocomplete in the IPython Console.

That's a separate project that we just embed in Spyder, so we can't do anything about it (other than waiting for someone to add support for it later on :)

Comment: IPython lists Code completion as supported feature: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/ipythonconsole.html#supported-features

Comment: Is that still true? `Spyder 4.1.3`: IPython console, I get plenty of popups: I'd like to disable pop-ups as they are too difficult to escape. And I don't use them anyways. I don't see how to disable them in preferences under "IPython Console". Or do I need to disable under "Completion and linting"? Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickT, please go to `Tools > Preferences > Display` and deactivate the option called `Show calltips`.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, Awesome, thanks! On MacOS, it's in `python > IPython Console > Display > Show calltips`.